# ¿Sabeis alguna expresión regular para validar el NIE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net

Tengo la expresión regular para validar un DNI, pero no hay manera de encontrar una para validar NIE y DNI, o al menos una que valide un NIE.

Es para validar un formulario con validaciones personalizadas (`ValidationAttribute`).

Si me podeis echar un cable os lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado una función que funciona a la perfección y cortita:

```
 public class DNIAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object NIF)
    {
        string patron = "[A-HJ-NP-SUVW][0-9]{7}[0-9A-J]|\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]|[X]\\d{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]|[X]\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]|[YZ]\\d{0,7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]";
        string sRemp = "";
        bool ret = false;
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(patron);
        sRemp = rgx.Replace(NIF.ToString(), "OK");
        if (sRemp == "OK") ret = true;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

fuente: http://comino.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/como-validar-la-entrada-del-cif-nif-nie.html

Gracias de todos modos a los que habeis contestado, tambien necesitaré el codijo javascript y me será de ayuda ;-)

Comment: Tiene buena pinta, hace algo similar a lo que te comentaba en mi respuesta usando `|` para tener una expresión regular condicional, es este caso he contado 5. De todas formas te faltaría la comprobación del dígito de control que eso no se puede hacer con expresión regular (depende de lo que estés haciendo, igual tampoco lo necesitas). Saludos

Answer (score 5):

En [este](http://www.michublog.com/informatica/8-funciones-para-la-validacion-de-formularios-con-expresiones-regulares) artículo puedes encontar algoritmos de validación de NIF, NIE y DNI que,  aunque están en JavaScript, tienen muy buena pinta. Traducirlos a C# no debería ser complicado. El código es el siguiente:

```
function nif_valido($nif) {
    $nif = strtoupper($nif);

    $nifRegEx = '/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i';
    $nieRegEx = '/^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i';

    $letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";

    if (preg_match($nifRegEx, $nif)) return ($letras[(substr($nif, 0, 8) % 23)] == $nif[8]);
    else if (preg_match($nieRegEx, $nif)) {
        if ($nif[0] == "X") $nif[0] = "0";
        else if ($nif[0] == "Y") $nif[0] = "1";
        else if ($nif[0] == "Z") $nif[0] = "2";

        return ($letras[(substr($nif, 0, 8) % 23)] == $nif[8]);
    }
    else return false;
}

function cif_valido($cif) {
    $cif = strtoupper($cif);

    $cifRegEx1 = '/^[ABEH][0-9]{8}$/i';
    $cifRegEx2 = '/^[KPQS][0-9]{7}[A-J]$/i';
    $cifRegEx3 = '/^[CDFGJLMNRUVW][0-9]{7}[0-9A-J]$/i';

    if (preg_match($cifRegEx1, $cif) || preg_match($cifRegEx2, $cif) || preg_match($cifRegEx3, $cif)) {
        $control = $cif[strlen($cif) - 1];
        $suma_A = 0;
        $suma_B = 0;

        for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
            if ($i % 2 == 0) $suma_A += intval($cif[$i]);
            else {
                $t = (intval($cif[$i]) * 2);
                $p = 0;

                for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($t); $j++) {
                    $p += substr($t, $j, 1);
                }
                $suma_B += $p;
            }
        }

        $suma_C = (intval($suma_A + $suma_B)) . "";
        $suma_D = (10 - intval($suma_C[strlen($suma_C) - 1])) % 10;

        $letras = "JABCDEFGHI";

        if ($control >= "0" && $control <= "9") return ($control == $suma_D);
        else return (strtoupper($control) == $letras[$suma_D]);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

En cuanto a la validación se puede diferenciar dos partes, una primera que se puede hacer con expresiones regulares y que se asegura de que el formato es el correcto y una segunda fase que calcula y comprueba el dígito de control.

Lo que podrías hacer es ejecutar la validación con expresión regular en cliente y realizar una segunda validación en servidor donde compruebes los dígitos de control

Puedes construir una expresión regular condicional usando `|` que engloba las dos validaciones:

```
^([0-9]{8}[A-Z])|[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$
```

Y pos si no te fías demasiado de los algoritmos, [aquí](http://www.interior.gob.es/web/servicios-al-ciudadano/dni/calculo-del-digito-de-control-del-nif-nie) tienes la página del ministerio del interior con las especificaciones del cálculo del dígito de control

Answer (score 2):

Podrias evaluar lo comentado aqui

[Validación CIF, NIF y NIE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/4b6560a0-82aa-4a8f-8e24-29769e69ad05/validacin-cif-nif-y-nie?forum=vcses)

entiendo que la parte importante seria

```
const string correspondencia = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET";

if (!Regex.IsMatch(nie, @"[K-MX-Z]\d{7}[" + correspondencia + "]$")){
   //invalida
}
```